# JavaScript if answer is correct, generate new string

Tags: javascript, function, loops, repeat

I have a program that randomly generates two numbers (x and y) and asks the user to multiply them. Once they multiply them, it will tell them if they get it right or wrong. The thing I'm having problems with is that if they get the answer correct, it should then generate a new set of numbers. I'm not sure how to make the program perform that function again. Also it has to clear the answer field no matter if they get it right or wrong. Thanks!

```
var x, y; // global variables for randomly generated numbers
var correct = ['Very good!', 'Excellent!', 'Correct - Nice work!', 'Correct - Keep up the good work!'];
var incorrect = ['No. please try again.', 'Wrong. Try once more.', 'Incorrect - Dont give up!', 'No - Keep trying.'];

// getting two random numbers between 1-12 then assigning them to x and y

function generateNumbers() {
    function aNumber() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    }
    x = aNumber();
    y = aNumber();
}

// generating the question that will be used with the random numbers x and y
function genQuestion() {
    generateNumbers();
    document.getElementById('question').value = x + " times " + y;
}

// function that is performed when the button "check answer" is clicked. It will generate one of 4 answers depending 
//if it's right or wrong and will add 1 to the value of total. If it's incorrect it won't add anything
function buttonPressed() {
    var correctans = correct[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]; // randomly selecting an answer if it's correct
    var incorrectans = incorrect[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]; // randomly selecting an answer if it's incorrect
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;

    if (answer == x * y) // correct
        {
            function genQuestion() {
                generateNumbers();
                document.getElementById('question').value = x + " times " + y;
            }
            window.alert(correctans);
            var total = document.getElementById('total').value++;
        }
    else {              // incorrect
        window.alert(incorrectans); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the genQuestion function, and it makes little sense to redefine it.

```
// function that is performed when the button "check answer" is clicked. It will generate one of 4 answers depending 
//if it's right or wrong and will add 1 to the value of total. If it's incorrect it won't add anything
function buttonPressed() {
    var correctans = correct[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]; // randomly selecting an answer if it's correct
    var incorrectans = incorrect[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]; // randomly selecting an answer if it's incorrect
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;

    if (answer == x * y) // correct
        {
            //call genQuestion to create new question
            genQuestion(); 
            window.alert(correctans);
            var total = parseInt(document.getElementById('total').value)++;
        }
    else {              // incorrect
        window.alert(incorrectans); 
    }
    //clear 'answer' field
    document.getElementById('answer').value = '';
}
```